# Jtable textbox depends on

Tags: jquery, jtable

I am working on a Jtable(jquery) project and I need to populate a textbox with a value comming from mysql depending on what I choose on a combobox.

Is this possible? or is just posible to populate comboboxes in cascade?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes it is possible.
Try this

jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            try
        {
            Connection con=null;
            Statement st=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url=null,userID=null,password=null;
                    String dbFileName=null;
                    String sql=null;

                    dbFileName = "C:/db.accdb";
                    url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                            "DBQ="+dbFileName+";";
                    Object name=jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);//,"system","manager"
                    st=con.createStatement();

    rs= st.executeQuery("select column1,column2 from Table where Name='"+name+"'");
                   while(rs.next())
            {
                jTextField4.setText(rs.getString(1));
                                jTextField5.setText(rs.getString(2));
                          }
                    con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("GG"+e);
        }

        } 
        });
```